# Systemd: How to get a timer to run after a required service?

Tags: systemd, raspbian, services, systemd-timer

Currently, I have this *systemd* timer (`my.timer`):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=30 
Unit=my-subsequent.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The timer is set to activate upon boot due to: `systemctl enable my.timer` and `systemctl start my.timer`.

Upon activation, the timer waits for 30 seconds, then it starts the service `my-subsequent.service`.

**However,** instead of having the timer activate upon boot, I would like it to wait for *another service* (`my-preceding.service`) to activate upon boot.

So that the chain is: *boot* > `my-preceding.service` > `my.timer` > `my-subsequent.service`.

How can I accomplish this?

---

Edit:

I tried to find if I can use `After=` and `Requires=` in timers, but didn't find anything. This does however seem to work at first glance. Is it an acceptable solution?

```
[Unit]
Description=My Timer
After=my-preceding.service
Requires=my-preceding.service

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=30 
Unit=my-subsequent.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `After=`, and `Requires=` is the correct approach for ordering services. You may also want to note that if a service specified in `Requires` fails, so will your service. From the manpage:

```
Often, it is a better choice to use Wants= instead of Requires= in order to 
achieve a system that is more robust when dealing with failing services.
```

Comment: You wrote services, but do you also include timers in this?

Comment: Yes, unit configurations for both timers, and services are the same in systemd i.e. the `[Unit]` section is generic to both types of config files. This is also the same with the `[Install]` section. You can check this out for more information: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html